# Error in rasterFromXYZ(xyz = centroids[, c("lon", "lat", "id")], crs = WGS84) : y cell sizes are not regular

Tags: raster, coordinate-system, r, wgs84

I'm trying to convert a csv file set of values into a raster but keep receiving the above error.

```
#Set raster options to improve speed of calculation
rasterOptions(tmptime = 4,
              progress = "text", #displays raster operation progress bar
              timer = TRUE, #outputs raster calculation duration 
              maxmemory = 10e+9, #max no. of bytes to read into memory
              chunksize = 5e+9, #max no. of bytes to read/write in a single chunk while processing disk-based raster objects
              tmpdir = tmp_path) #location for writing temporary file

#Define CRS
WGS84 <- "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"

#select csv file containing RR predicted poverty
pov_csv_path <- "" #paste CSV Flile

#set csv path's parent directory as working directory 
setwd(dirname(dirname(pov_csv_path)))

#load csv to dataframe
df_pov<- read.csv(pov_csv_path)

#Subset the predicted poverty dataframe to get the grid ID & lat and lon
centroids <- df_pov %>%
  select(id,lon,lat)

#Make a raster from centroids
#Function generates raster from regular grids like dataset used - assumes minimum distance between x & y coordinates is raster resolution
centroid_rast <- rasterFromXYZ(xyz = centroids[,c("lon","lat","id")], crs=WGS84)
```

Link to CSV file used: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uUyNdhWQXLwGYHrfU3jKMRi5XkYrj6K2/view?usp=sharing

Error Message:

```
Error in rasterFromXYZ(xyz = centroids[, c("lon", "lat", "id")], crs = WGS84) : 
  y cell sizes are not regular
```

Comment: I've added the R tag - lots of people filter on tags for languages and so it helps if you tag the language!

Comment: This data has problems. The latitudes are greater than 90, which is impossible. Are lat and lon the wrong way round? The data are also a sparse set of points, and the error is because R is struggling to find a regular grid for them. Are you expecting these points to be on a regular grid? Have you plotted lon vs lat and does it make sense? It spans 40 units in lat and only 6 in lon...